# Displaying rows between two values in Fusion-Tables

Tags: between, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to figure out this Fusion-Tables and I want to display only the rows that have an assessed value between 500,000 and 750,000. I've been able to figure out how to show anything more than 500,000 but I don't know how to get to anything between two values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeByAssessedValue(formResults) {
        layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Address' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Assessed Value' > '"+ formResults+ "'");
    }
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no keyword like `BETWEEN` in Fusion Tables (see the [SQL reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference#Select) for details). But it's very easy to accomplish what you want using two conditions that can be combined using the keyword `AND`:

```
  SELECT 'Address' 
  FROM   1234
  WHERE  'Assessed Value' > 500000
  AND    'Assessed Value' < 750000
```

Remember to use `>=` and `<=` if the values "500,000" and "750,000" should be included in the results.